# How to duplicate folder then rename folder and files inside it in Batch or Powershell to multiple folders

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Let's say I have this folder structure:

```
02548 //let's call this MASTER FOLDER, folder name are using site_id
|- 1. Master File
  |- 02548_MSFI.pdf
|- 2. src
  |- 02548_main.cpp
|- 3. Backup
  |- alpha.svn
```

I also have site_id.txt file contains the name of side_id:

```
02548
03584
05482
07992
05861
```

What I want to do is to duplicate the **MASTER FOLDER** to new folders. So, the final result will be something like this:

```
|-02548 // MASTER FOLDER
| |- 1. Master File
|   |- 02548_MSFI.pdf
|  |- 2. src
|    |- 02548_main.cpp
|  |- 3. Backup
|    |- alpha.svn
|-03584 //the folder name are taken from the list inside the site_id.txt
| |- 1. Master File
|   |- 03584_MSFI.pdf //please notice the prefix of this file's name
|  |- 2. src
|    |- 03584_main.cpp //please notice the prefix of this file's name
|  |- 3. Backup
|    |- alpha.svn
|-05482 //the folder name are taken from the list inside the site_id.txt
| |- 1. Master File
|   |- 05482_MSFI.pdf //please notice the prefix of this file's name
|  |- 2. src
|    |- 05482_main.cpp //please notice the prefix of this file's name
|  |- 3. Backup
|    |- alpha.svn

and so on until all the site_id from site_id.txt are here.
```

In the real world, site_id.txt will contains more than 1000 of list. So, doing this manually will be very painful.
How do I do this using batch script or powershell?

Comment: What have you tried so far, where are you stuck? Regard that StackOverflow is not a free code writing service!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know how you would do it, but this is how I would do it if I had a job and that task was assigned to me:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q44093158.txt"

FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 XCOPY /s /e "%sourcedir%\t w o\*" "%destdir%\%%a\" >nul
 FOR /f "delims=" %%p IN ('dir /s /b "%destdir%\%%a\*#*"') DO (
  SET "filename=%%~nxp"
  CALL set "filename=%%filename:#=%%a%%"
  CALL REN "%%p" "%%filename%%"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q44093158.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Within the source directory, (I actually tested with `\t w o` appended to ensure it worked with directorynames containing spaces), build the structure including the master files with the branch-number replaced by `#`

The code simply reads `filename1` which contains the branch names one to a line, duplicates the directory structure at the destination, then looks for filenames containing `#`. With those files, it substitutes the branch name for the `#` and renames the file.

Done!

Comment: I tried that script, it can duplicate the folder and files but the filename on the new folders still are using the MASTER FOLDER site_id. What I did was only changed the "sourcedir", "destdir" and the "t w o".

Comment: I found taht at the end of the script it throw "File not found" in this line **CALL REN "%%p" "%%filename%%"**, I suppose it failed to get the "%%p" varibale from the delims ?

Comment: The template structure should be under a directory like "c:\template" as `sourcedir\t w o` which needs a copy of your entire `02548` subtree with all its files with the name changed to `#whatever` where they are currently `02548whatever`. The idea is that you have a template file structure and set of files which is copied and renamed using `#` as indicator to be replaced by the branch name

Comment: Now this worked, I made a small changes on the scripts

Answer (score 0):

This PowerShell script and the file site_id.txt should be placed in the parent folder of `02548`

```
## C:\Test\Copy-Template.ps1
$template = '02548'
foreach ($site in (Get-Content site_id.txt)) {
   Get-ChildItem $template -recurse | Foreach-Object {
     $NewName = $_.FullName -replace $template,$site
     if ($_.PSIsContainer){
       if (!(Test-path $NewName)){md $NewName|Out-Null}
     } else {
       copy $_.FullName $NewName -EA 0
     }
  }
}
```

Sample output:

```
> tree /F
C:.
│   Copy-Template.ps1
│   site_id.txt
│
└───02548
    ├───1. Master File
    │       02548_MSFI.pdf
    │
    ├───2. src
    │       02548_main.cpp
    │
    └───3. Backup
            alpha.svn

> .\Copy-Template.ps1
> tree /f
C:.
│   Copy-Template.ps1
│   site_id.txt
│
├───02548
│   ├───1. Master File
│   │       02548_MSFI.pdf
│   │
│   ├───2. src
│   │       02548_main.cpp
│   │
│   └───3. Backup
│           alpha.svn
│
├───03584
│   ├───1. Master File
│   │       03584_MSFI.pdf
│   │
│   ├───2. src
│   │       03584_main.cpp
│   │
│   └───3. Backup
│           alpha.svn
│
├───05482
...
├───05861
...
└───07992
    ├───1. Master File
    │       07992_MSFI.pdf
    │
    ├───2. src
    │       07992_main.cpp
    │
    └───3. Backup
            alpha.svn
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Call the subroutine, read data from site_id file
call :DuplicateTree < site_id.txt
goto :EOF


:DuplicateTree

rem Read MasterFolder from first line
set /P "masterFolder="

:nextFolder
   rem Read and process next folders until EOF
   set /P "nextFolder="
   if errorlevel 1 exit /B

   rem Duplicate folders first
   md "%nextFolder%"
   for /R "%masterFolder%" /D %%a in (*) do (
      set "folder=%%a"
      set "folder=!folder:*%cd%\=!"
      md "!folder:%masterFolder%=%nextFolder%!"
   )

   rem Duplicate files
   for /R "%masterFolder%" %%a in (*) do (
      set "file=%%a"
      set "file=!file:*%cd%\=!"
      copy "%%a" "!file:%masterFolder%=%nextFolder%!"
   )
goto nextFolder
```

Place this Batch file in the same folder that contain both `site_id.txt` file and `02548` Master Folder.